# JTable - lock columns for horizontal scroll

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Now in my application I simply added JTable to JScrollPane:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
```

I would like to implement feature similar to excel locking columns. Rows from all columns can be slided vertically. But when user slides horizontally first two columns stays in place.
Initial position of columns: `A|B||C|D|E`
After slide by two columns: `A|B||E|F|G`

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Here is one example: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy This example works great. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.